# perl stream file for regex token including scanned tokens

Tags: regex, perl, tokenize

I am trying to stream a file in perl and tokenize the lines and include the tokens.

I have:

```
while( $line =~ /([\/][\d]*[%].*?[%][\d]*[\/]|[^\s]+|[\s]+)/g ) {
  my $word = $1;
  #...
}
```

But it doesn't work when there's no spaces in the token.

For example, if my line is:

```
$line = '/15%one (1)(2)%15/ is a /%good (1)%/ +/%number(2)%/.'
```

I would like to split that line into:

```
$output =
[
  '/15%one (1)(2)%15/',
  ' ',
  'is',
  ' ',
  'a',
  '/%good (1)%/',
  ' ',
  '+',
  '/%number(2)%/',
  '.'
]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`, so

```
my @tokens;
push @tokens, $1
   while $line =~ m{
      \G
      ( \s+
      | ([\/])([0-9]*)%
        (?: (?! %\3\2 ). )*
        %\3\2
      | (?: (?! [\/][0-9]*% )\S )+
      )
   }sxg;
```

but that doesn't validate. If you want to validate, you could use

```
my @tokens;
push @tokens, $1
   while $line =~ m{
      \G
      ( \s+
      | ([\/])([0-9]*)%
        (?: (?! %\3\2 ). )*
        %\3\2
      | (?: (?! [\/][0-9]*% )\S )+
      | \z (*COMMIT) (*FAIL)
      | (?{ die "Syntax error" })
      )
   }sxg;
```

The following also validates, but it's a bit more readable and makes it easy to differentiate the token types.:

```
my @tokens;
for ($line) {
   m{\G ( \s+ ) }sxgc
      && do { push @tokens, $1; redo };

   m{\G ( ([\/])([0-9]*)%  (?: (?! %\3\2 ). )*  %\3\2 ) }sxgc
      && do { push @tokens, $1; redo };

   m{\G ( (?: (?! [\/][0-9]*% )\S )+ ) }sxgc
      && do { push @tokens, $1; redo };

   m{\G \z }sxgc
      && last;

   die "Syntax error";
}
```

[`pos`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html) will get you information about where the error occurred.